# How to make netcat print colourful text?

Tags: bash, netcat

on my Mac I have an peripheral that sends text data to `localhost:2332`. Some of them are coloured, like this: `"\e[1;31mRed text here\e[m normal text here"`, I use `nc loacal host` to monitor the data stream. However I noticed that the coloured text are not printed out properly, the output is like `[1;31mRed text here[m normal text here`. I am just wondering if there is some options I can use to make netcat parse the escape characters correctly.

Comment: I am thinking you will have to pipe the output through to a separate command. Maybe you can do something in perl?

Comment: Works for me. Are you running `nc` in a terminal? What version/implementation of `nc`. You may want to try `socat` instead.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Hi the nc is pretty old, I am using it on a Mac as I said. I tried ```socat``` but it is the same output.

Comment: `socat` for sure doesn't mangle the data it reads. So probably those `ESC` characters are not there to be received in the first place.